# Element identification problem in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\Drivers\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='uitk-tabs-button-container']/li[2]/a/span").click()
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "location-field-leg1-origin-dialog-trigger").send_keys("BLR")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "location-field-leg1-destination-dialog-trigger").send_keys("BOM")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "departure").send_keys("Fri Nov 06 2020")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/p/a").click()
```

I am trying to identify the elements

> Flights(link), origin(inputbox), destination(inputbox), date(inputbox) and search(link)

but no luck... always getting

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:...

I am a beginner to selenium, please help.

Comment: I tried in other websites as well but I could not find the right element ID / name / xpath... there are so much information if I do Inspect element. Kindly someone help

Comment: As an aside: Don't use `driver.implicitly_wait` *and* `time.sleep` -- just the former and set it to whatever maximum value you think is necessary at the start of the program. You will then wait until the elements are found up to a maximum of the time specified. But if you say `time.sleep(15)`, you will always wait 15 seconds even if the elements are available much sooner.

Comment: Which statement throws the exception? Include the stacktrace.

Comment: When I run this it seems to fail looking for id "location-field-leg1-origin-dialog-trigger". When I inspect the form that is shown after the first successful click, it is initialized for a round trip but you are specifying no return date, your departure date seems to be the wrong format ('Nov 6' would be correct based on what gets populated when you click on the calendar and select a date) and I cannot find an input field with the id you are looking for. Are we looking at the same form? You should also make sure you "quit" the driver whether you get an exception or not (`try/finally`).

Comment: Let’s make the requirement simpler; help me to click on the Flights button and then entering the flight from/to details as the script fails here itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because ultimately to set the departure and return dates you have to click on the calendar and select various date buttons. Perhaps a more detailed investigation might reveal a way of executing a JavaScript script to add the dates to the underlying widgets. But I will try to at least get you started. The main issue is that to enter, for example, a departure airport, you have to first click on the departure button, which then brings up a formerly hidden input area into which you can now enter your info (followed by a RETURN to close the input):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\Drivers\chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='uitk-tabs-button-container']/li[2]/a/span").click()

    # Leaving from:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/figure/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/figure/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/header/section/div/input").send_keys("BLR" + Keys.RETURN)

    # Arriving to:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/figure/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/button").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/figure/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/header/section/div/input").send_keys("BOM" + Keys.RETURN)

    # Departing:
    # open calendar:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "d1-btn").click()
    input('pausing so you can see the calendar...')
    # pick dates (this is the tricky bit) -- code omitted:
    # finally click "Done":
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/figure/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button").click()
finally:
    input('pausing before termination...')
    driver.quit()
```

**Note that the browser window must have the focus (be the current window) or the `find_element` calls might fail.** Anyway, that has been my experience.

**This is what I see:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: no luck, scripts fails again at "Leaving From" step.. Message: no such element: Unable to locate elemet.

Comment: It works for me. I've updated the answer to show what I see. Make sure that the Chrome window has the focus, that is, switch to the Chrome window as soon as it pops up.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the Chrome window is focused or not :( could you please help me to set the focus?

Comment: I just mean that when the Chrome window driven by Selenium opens up, quickly make it the current window.

Comment: I didn't get that, actually I have closed all the browser window before running the script. So technically only one window opened while execution. How do I make sure that Selenium is focusing on that window?..

Comment: There is also the window from which you are running the Python code!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That is the current window when you start your script. You need to tab to the Selenium browser window when it starts up (or just click on its title bar). I don't know how to make this clearer..

Comment: I got your point, it is in the browser window while execution, no issues with that.. the script works until the Flights section... it is failing from the step where we select the leaving from city.

Comment: Well, you can see from my image that I am able to plug in the departure city, the arriving city, and get the calendar to pop up. And I get as far as the statement `input('pausing so you can see the calendar...')`. I don't know what else to tell you.